# Deadlock graph interpretation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

We have SQL Server 2016.

We faced this deadlock issue and we don't understand something in the deadlock graph.

Here is how we are interpreting this:

*The two processes in question were not waiting on each other. They were waiting on themselves and trying to acquire the same lock on the same resource in spite of already being the owner of that lock.*

I think something is not right with this interpretation.
Could someone more knowledgeable explain what happened here?
The isolation level is READ_COMMITTED.

If one could explain every bit here that would be really helpful.

Many thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: There is information in the second section of the XML that will help identify what is going on here. What I suspect is that the two locks were on separate parts of the index, and (probably) both locks needed to expand - perhaps from a row lock to a page lock. At that point, both locks conflicted with each other, resulting in a deadlock. But with this, we don't know if one is in a transaction, or what type (serializable, repeatable, etc); if these are both on the same SPID; and a lot of other info that could help in analysis.

Comment: A personal bugaboo - if you can post actual text (instead of a picture of text), it helps people trying to help you immensely.

Comment: @Ben Thul I know. Sorry all I got was a picture.

Answer (score 0):

A deadlock occurs when two processes are trying to get at some data object, but each cannot complete as long as the other process is running. SQL Server picks one to run and one to be the victim.

In your pic, it appears that process 8557c42ca8 has a shared lock on something and process d468 has an exclusive lock on something. Each process is also a waiter and waiting on the process. So as long as neither process can proceed until one of the processes releases their lock, they are in an infinite loop.

Comment: Yes but the question is isn't that thing (they are trying to lock) the same thing?

Comment: @peter.petrov Probably not. Post the graphical deadlock graph and the entirety of the XML and you will have some more info

Answer (score 0):

> The two processes in question were not waiting on each other. They were waiting on themselves

No.  Each session owns a lock on a key and waits on a lock on the key locked by the other.

> Could someone more knowledgeable explain what happened here?

You'd need to post the rest of the deadlock graph, the table definition (including indexes) and the code that each session had run from the beginning of its transaction up to the deadlock.

Comment: Yes but the question is isn't that thing (they are trying to lock) the same thing?

Comment: No. The two locks are both Key Locks, but on different keys. Post the full deadlock XML in your question to verify. The key lock hashes are printed in the <process-list>.